# How does a pdf change after a variable transformation with another random variable?

Tags: random-variable, density-function

I have a probability density function of the energy $f(E)$ of a distribution of particles. Now, each energy gets shifted according to an angle $\theta$: $$E_{after} = E_{before} + g(E_{before}) \cos \theta$$
The angle $\theta$ is different for each particle (a random variable) and distributed according to $f_{\theta}(\theta) = \sin(\theta)/2$ with $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, i.e. isotropic in 3 dimensions. The function $g(E)$ is known in general (assume e.g. $g(E) = E$ or $1$ for simplicity).

Given that I know $f(E_{before})$, can I get an expression for $f(E_{after})$?

I assume I have to write it as a distribution in two variables $f(E_{after}, \theta)$ and then marginalize over $\theta$ but I am not sure how to do this.

A simple example with a $f(E)$ = 1 and $g(E)$ = E looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 10000000
sample = np.random.rand(size)
thetas = np.arccos( -2 * np.random.rand(size) + 1.) #inverse CDF smapling

shifted = sample + sample * np.cos(thetas)

plt.figure()
plt.hist(sample, density = True, bins = 100, alpha = 0.8, label = "original distribution")
plt.hist(shifted, density = True, bins = 100, alpha = 0.8, label = "shifted distribution")
plt.xlabel("energies")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.legend()
```

[image]
What is the analytical expression for the orange distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming $E_{before}$ to $X$, $E_{after}$ to $Y$, and using a capital $\Theta$ to denote the random angle variable, we have this expression for the cumulative density function for Y (the cdf), assuming $X$ and $\Theta$ are independent:

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y < y) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\Theta}(\theta)f_X(x)\mathbb{1}_{x + g(x)cos(\theta)<y}dx d\theta
$$

Where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function for the event $A$.

You can then differentiate this cdf to find the pdf.

Edit: the indicator function is 1 when the condition in its subscript is satisfied and 0 otherwise. What this means in practice is that the limits of the integral should be adjusted to only include regions where the indicator function is 1. For your example, $Y = (1 + cos(\Theta))X$, for each $y$ there are 2 cases:

- If $X < \frac{y}{2}$ then $Y < y$ regardless of the value of $cos(\Theta)$. So we integrate over the whole range $(0, 2\pi)$ of possible values of $\Theta$.
- If $X > \frac{y}{2}$ then $Y < y$ only if $cos(\Theta)<\frac{y}{X}-1$, i.e. $\Theta > arccos(\frac{y}{x}-1)$.

And the joint pdf $f_{X,\Theta}(x,\theta)$ is uniformly $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

So the cdf is as below, where the two integrals correspond to the above two cases:

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y < y) \:=\: \int_{0}^{\frac{y}{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\pi}\:d\theta\:dx \:+\: \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1}\int_{arccos(\frac{y}{x}-1)}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\pi}\:d\theta \: dx\\
$$

Comment: Could you show how one could use this expression to obtain a solution for the simple example plotted above? I am not sure how one would deal with the indicator function in the integral.

Comment: I added the integral for your example.

Comment: ah, I see, Im not used to that notation. So it would be equivalent to saying $\mathbb{P}(Y<y) = \int_{\Omega_y} f_\Theta (\theta) f_X (x) d \Omega_y$ with $\Omega_y =  \{(x, \theta) | x + g(x)cos(\theta) < y\}$ ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: fantastic, thank you so much. Just a quick pointer that actually $f_{X, \Theta}(x, \theta) = f_X(x) * f_\Theta(\theta) = 1 * sin(\theta) /2$ for the example I gave above which makes the orange pdf $-ln(y/2)/2$

Comment: You're right, I misread as $f_{\Theta}$ being uniform on $[0,\pi]$.